# strace restart apache server does not log accept/accept4 syscalls

Tags: linux, web-server, apache2, kernel

We are using the following command to gather syscalls for apache server start (run as root):

```
strace -e trace=open,close,read,write,connect,accept -f -o /home/sacumen/syscalls_start_apache.txt systemctl restart apache2
```

We expect that the syscalls_start_apache.txt file will have accept calls but all it has are close and read calls:

```
87017 close(3)                          = 0
87017 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
87017 close(3)                          = 0
87017 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
87017 close(3)                          = 0
87017 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
87017 close(3)                          = 0
87017 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
87017 close(3)                          = 0
87017 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
87017 close(3)                          = 0
87017 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
87017 close(3)                          = 0
87017 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
87017 close(3)                          = 0
87017 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\237\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
87017 close(3)                          = 0
87017 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
87017 close(3)                          = 0
87017 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
87017 close(3)                          = 0
87017 read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\ttmpfs\nnodev\tbd"..., 1024) = 392
87017 read(3, "", 1024)
```

Our question is whether or not a web server perform an accept/accept4 to listen on the socket at port 80, say.

Kindly let us know.

Comment: At first glance: you're debugging `systemctl` rather than apache httpd. You might want to attempt to run the `ExecStart=` commandline from the apache2 service unit directly to run `strace` or modify the systemd service.